# How to compute the degree of this branched covering between two compact Riemann surfaces?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces

Let $S_g$ be the compact Riemann surface of genus $g$. For $g>1,\, $we can construct a holomorphic map from $S_g$ to $S_1$ as below:
$S_g \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^g/\mathbb{Z}^{2g} \rightarrow S_1=\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}^2.$

The first map $\varphi:S_g \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^g/\mathbb{Z}^{2g}$ is Albanese map.(See Huybrechts *Complex Geometry : An Introduction* Definition 3.3.7)

The second map $\psi:\mathbb{C}^g/\mathbb{Z}^{2g} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}^2\,$is the projection, i.e. $\psi([(z_1,...,z_g)])=[z_1].$(The bracket [] means the eqivalent class defined by the quotient.)

This is a nonconstant holomorphic map between two compact Riemann surfaces thus a branched covering. My question is how can I compute the degree of it?

Comment: This is not a very canonical construction. Not only do you have to *choose* an isomorphism $\mathrm{Alb}(S_g)\cong\mathbb{C}^g/\mathbb{Z}^{2g}$, the nature of the projection $\mathbb{C}^g/\mathbb{Z}^{2g}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}^2$ changes according to this identification as well.